# how can I know if a file open dialog is confirmed or not in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to submit a form when a file open dialog is confirmed. I don't know how to do that using jquery. Can anyone help me?

Suppose I'll browse an image file from local and when I click open button on the dialog box at the same time I need to submit a form.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a javascript function after the selection of file from the Open Dialog window close event. in HTMLusing html file type="file"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805977/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-after-the-selection-of-file-from-the-open-dial)

Comment: Try google next time. Most questions of this nature have been answered before. In additon I would recommend checking out [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications).

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching a change event to your `file` input. When a file is selected from the dialog, the event will fire and you can submit your form:

```
<form ... >
   <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" />
</form>
```

Attach a listener to the `change` event, and submit the form:

```
$("#myFile").on("change", function (evt) {
   $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

If the dialog is cancelled, no event is triggered.